# Why is my bean null?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, spring-test

I am trying to learn how to use applicationContext. My goal is to swap out a mock data repository for a real one when using my unit tests. I don't want to do this explicitly, I want to do this with dependency injection.

So as a simple test before I make things complicated, I'm simply trying to get a bean out of my applicationContext.xml. From what I've read, this should work:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext.xml")
public class ResultsListTests {

     @Resource
     CompanyResult resultBean;

     @Test
     public void shouldAddResults() {
         assertEquals(resultBean.getCompanyName(), "Microsoft");
```

But my resultBean is always null. Here is my applicationContext.xml, which is located under WebContent/WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <bean id="resultBean" name="resultBean" class="com.trgr.cobalt.company.domain.CompanyResult">
        <property name="companyName">
            <value>Microsoft</value>
        </property>
     </bean>
</beans>
```

So why is my resultBean always null? What have I done incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext.xml")
public class ResultsListTests {

     @Resource
     CompanyResult resultBean;

     @Test
     public void shouldAddResults() {
         assertEquals(resultBean.getCompanyName(), "Microsoft");
     }
}
```

**BTW**, in your sample, `WebContent/WEB-INF` is not the proper location for `applicationContext.xml`.

If you specify `@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext.xml")` then Spring will look for `applicationContext.xml` at the root of the classpath, not in `WebContent/WEB-INF` (jUnit is 100% unaware of the fact that this is a web application).

**For more information**, see [Spring reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Two questions. 1) SpringJUnit4ClassRunner cannot be resolved to a type. What's up with that? 2) While it is helpful to know that my applicationContext.xml is in the wrong place, it would be much MORE helpful to know the right place to put it ("the root of the classpath" doesn't mean much to me, as I'm very new to Spring and Java). I have read the chapter on BeanFactory and ApplicationContext and apparently they expect you to know where it goes.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? And how is your project organized (source folder layout)?

Comment: I am using 3.0.5. My Java Resources contains a src folder and a few test folders. My src folder has nothing but packages. I was told that I should add a resources folder under Java Resources and put my applicationContext.xml in there, and then I could reference it with WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml. It is not clear to me how Java Resources/resources maps to WEB-INF/classes, but that wouldn't be the first time I've been frustrated by Java's insistence upon smoke and mirrors when it comes to folder structure. In any case, do you agree with this or do you have a different suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before, but my @RunWith annotation works fine now and my applicationContext is loading. Thanks for the tips!