# So NOW why is my bean null?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207620/why-is-my-bean-null) regarding pulling beans out of an applicationContext. The answer was indeed helpful, but now it seems I have a problem with accessing this bean from a class outside the test. In other words, my test instantiates a class which uses a bean from an application context, but this bean keeps coming up null.

My test sets up the application context like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext-test.xml")
public class SearcherTests {
```

My test programmatically instantiates the Repository class:

```
    Repository searcher = new Repository();
```

My Repository class has the following member variable:

```
 @Resource
 private MyFactory myFactory;
```

If I understand Spring correctly, this should look to the current application context for a bean named `myFactory`. According to the test, the current application context should be `applicationContext-test.xml`, which contains a definition for `myFactory`:

```
 <bean id="myFactory" 
    name="myFactory" 
    class="com.foo.Mocks"
    factory-method="createMockFactory" />
```

In the future, this factory method will return a mock. But at the moment, it just returns a regular `Factory` object:

```
public class Mocks {

 public static MyFactory createMockFactory() {
  return new MyFactory();
 }
}
```

When I run the app from my browser, the `myFactory` variable was correctly instantiated from the bean definition in `applicationContext.xml`. In my test, to make sure that my `applicationContext-test.xml` is working, I have this same bean listed as a member variable just like I do in the `Repository` class. While running the test, the `myFactory` variable in the file containing the test looks exactly as I'd expect it to. However, when I get to the `Repository` class, the `myFactory` variable in that class is null. It seems as though this class is not instantiating the `myFactory` variable based on the bean definition in `applicationContext-test.xml`. Can someone tell me why?

**Update**

I changed the `searcher` variable so that it is a Spring bean, rather than instantiating the `Repository` class manually, and now the `myFactory` variable has been populated within the `Repository` class. Can someone explain why this needs to be a bean in order to work?

Comment: How does it obtain `Repository`? Is it a Spring bean?

Comment: No, Repository is not a Spring bean. My test actually instantiates a class, which in turn instantiates the Repository class. All of this instantiation is done programmatically.

Comment: I changed Repository to be a Spring bean and this works now. Not sure why it needs to be a bean for this to work. *scratches head*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you instantiate `Repository` yourself, then Spring doesn't get involved, and the dependencies won't get injected. It doesn't happen magically, Spring has to be in the loop somehow - the instance has to be passed through Spring processing layers, and a direct instantiation prevents that.

Comment: This class is instantiated directly within the application code, and yet the dependency gets injected just fine. The only difference I'm aware of between these two scenarios is that when the app is running, the applicationContext is loaded by web.xml. However, I'm new to Spring so there may be other differences of which I'm not aware. If you could clarify on this, I would appreciate it, as I'd like to understand Spring better.